# How to get values from dict of dict of list?

Tags: python

I have list of upper and lower bound for int value from dict of dict:

```
dicts={'params':{'max':[10,11]}}
```

Is there a way to get the value of int 10 and 11 separately?

I tried:

```
for k in dicts.values():
    print k
```

But that doesn't give me what I want.

Comment: why not `l, u = dicts['params']['max']` ?

Comment: Do you want to print everything in the dict of dict, or just the the `max` element of `params`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep going down the nested structure:

```
for k in dicts.values():    # k is a dict itself
    for lst in k.values():  # k's values are lists (at least the one you show
        for item in lst:    # iterate the lists
            print(item)
```

Or, if you only want one particular item:

```
for i in dicts['params']['max']:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your 'k' is a dict which defined in the 'dicts' var with the value is the 10 and 11 list. So you need other for loop to traversal the inner dict or use double index to indicate the return value.